# How can I target EVERY link and button on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange, target

I have a shopping cart that contains a form field and a checkbox in each row.  The form field controls the quantity, which can be edited, if the customer wants to modify the quantity of the product they order, and the checkbox selects the item, either to toss the item in a wish list, or to remove it.  The Add To Wish list and Remove Functions are separated out of this particular question.

What, I am looking at doing, is detecting when the form has been changed, and then targeting EVERY anchor tag and button on the page, so if the items have been modified, the script stops the click through and pops up a bootstrap modal, alerting the user that something in their cart has been modified.

**HTML** *(the shopping cart row, run through a JSTL forEach loop, but the markup is this):*

```
<table>
<form id="shoppingCart" action="updateTheCart.action">
     <c:forEach var="item" items="${shoppingCart.items}" varStatus="status">
          <tr class="cart-row">
               <td class="remove" data-label="Remove">
                    <label>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="removeFlag(<c:out value="${status.count}"/>)" value="true"/>
                    </label>
               </td>
               <td class="title" data-label="Title">
                    ${item.value.sellableGood.name}
               </td>
               <td class="qty" data-label="Quantity">
                    <input type="num" class="form-control qty-input" name="quantity(<c:out value="${status.count}" />)" value="<c:out value="${item.value.quantity}" />"/>    
               </td>
               <td class="subtotal" data-label="Line Total">
                    <fmt:formatNumber type="currency" pattern="$#,##0.00" value="${item.value.itemExtendedTotal}" />
               </td>
          </tr>
     </c:foreach>
</table>

<p><a href="checkout.action" id="checkout">Checkout</a></p>
<p><button type="submit" id="checkout">Update Cart</button></p>
<p><button id="addToWishlist" type="submit" id="wish-list">Add To Wish List</button></p>
<p><a href="/" id="shop-more">Chontinue Shopping</a></p>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#shoppingCart :input").change(function() {
     $("#shoppingCart").data("changed",true);
});
```

I know I am missing a LOT, but I really don't know where to begin at this point.

Comment: `change` events propagate, you don't have to add a listener to every input, just add it to `body`.

Comment: And you can do the same with `click` events.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'a, button', function(event){ /*Your stuff */});` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Why is there a `<form>` directly inside of a `<table>`? That's not how a table works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [onbeforeunload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != "" )
        window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
;[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a, button'), function(element) {
  //do something with buttons and links, for example:
  element.setAttribute('data-changed', true')
});
```

The jquery equivalent is:

```
$('a, button').each(function(element) {})
```

To watch the form for changes, I would use the `blur` event, it's the reverse of focus:

```
;[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myForm input'), function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
    //something has changed
  })
});
```

Jquery:

```
$('#myForm input').on('blur', function(event) {})
```